# What Data Structure should be used to store a large sentence (may be millions of words) with repetition of words

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I came across a question.
There is a sentence (say contains millions of words) and words are repetitive (e.g. Sentence is: "my name is ram, my name is shyam, ram is an engineer, shyam is also an engineer" and so on).

Goal is:

1. Memory should be efficiently used (word should be stored only once)
2. The sentence must be re-construct-able from the data structure.

Can someone suggest what data structure should be best suitable for this requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these are the only requirements, I would use a simple byte array.

The key is to pre-processing and post-processing. As a pre-processor I will use a good string compressor, such as GZIP or 7z. As you would expect, a post-processor will just decompress data.

Comment: Quite the opposite. It will be take very little space, in fact nearly the smallest you can ever get with any general string.

Comment: We do not want to compress and decompress. Let the raw data be stored in the memory.

Comment: @KaushalendraMishra you'd want to edit your question and state that requirement as this approach will, in general case, take least possible memory IMO.

Comment: @oleksii was thinking as consuming an input stream, not loading everything. seems this is not the case. also seems it's more of a programming exercise than getting the best solution

Comment: @KaushalendraMishra Given the two stated requirements, compression/decompression is exactly the right thing to do.  But you don't like that solution, which suggests to me that there are actually other things you want to be doing with the sentence besides just (1) storing it in a small amount of space and (2) being able to reconstruct it.  For example, maybe you want to be able to answer queries about how many times a word appears, or search it to find a substring.  If so, those uses should be mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can only store a word once, the natural solution is to store each unique word once and list the indices where each word occurs.  I would use a hash table of some sort that maps strings to a list of unsigned integrals (the number of bytes in the data type depending on the length of the text), the integrals being the position of each word.

Answer (score 0):

One possible method is by using these three data structures: 
1) Vector of integer (say V1), to store index of word in V2 
 
2) Vector of string (say V2), to store different words 
3) Map with key=string and data=integer (say M), to check if current word is new or already occured and if already occured, it points to index in V2 
**Steps to store:**
1) Extract a word from sentence 
2) Check if this word already exist in map M 
-> 2.1) if it exists, get the data value respective to this key and store in *index* 
-> 2.2) if does not exist, insert at end of V2 and get it's *index*, and store word with index as a pair in M 
3) Store *index* at end of V1
4) If sentence not ended goto 1)
**Steps to re-construct:**
Create empty string data structure to store *sentence*
1) Read integer from V1 and store in *index*
2) Append the string for V2 at *index* to *string*
3) Repeat for every integer in V1 in order from starting till end
Note: To take care of special characters like space, newline, etc. count them as separate words.